# Mixed Content Error when sending Ajax request to Rails server on Heroku

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax, heroku

I am working on a Rails app and am using AJAX to update a page as part of a live search feature. The code works locally but when I push to Heroku I see the following error occurs when the AJAX request is fired:

```
Mixed Content: The page at 'https://hipster-meet.herokuapp.com/users' was loaded over HTTPS, 
but requested an insecure XMLHttpRequest
endpoint 'http://hipster-meet.herokuapp.com/users?query=a'. 
This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS
```

I am serving jquery through the asset pipeline.

In my `production.rb` I have included the line:

```
config.force_ssl = true
```

This is the javascript that is sending the request:

```
ready = ->
  $('.search-field').keyup ->
    query = $('.search-field').val()
    $.getJSON('/users', {query: query})
    return

  $(document).ajaxSuccess (e, xhr, options, data) ->
    resultArea = $('.search-results')
    if data.length
      resultList = data.map (user)->
        return '<li class="result-item">' + user.username + '<hr/></li>'
      resultArea.html resultList
    else
      resultArea.html '<h5 class="text text-center">No Results, Sorry.</h5>'
      return
    return
  return

$(document).ready(ready)
$(document).on('page:load', ready)
```

I even tried including `force_ssl` in my `application_controller.rb` but the error persists.

Any ideas on what I am doing wrong?

Comment: How are you loading jQuery?  It it asset pipeline or from a CDN?

Comment: Can you post answer If it got fixed.

Comment: @TravisSmithplease share what solved the problem